# Y Offset, Tracks on a tank - Trigonometry

Tags: java, android, graphics, trigonometry

Tank tracks need to be either side of the tank, tank can face 360 rotation. Here is a picture to explain this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNHSP.jpg

The tank tracks are only offsetting horizontally at the moment, I'm trying to offset them vertically along the core of the tank (not working).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
private void tracksPosition()
{
    _DegreeToRadien = Math.toRadians(_degrees);

    _ObjectXCenter = (int) (_object_x + ((_itemAnimation.getWidth() / 2)) - _trackAnimationLeft.getWidth() / 2);
    _ObjectYCenter = (int) (_object_y + ((_itemAnimation.getHeight() / 2)) - _trackAnimationLeft.getHeight() / 2);

    //For left track
    _xOffset = -1 * (_itemAnimation.getHeight() / 2);

    _trackLeftPosition.set
    (
        (int)(((_xOffset) * Math.cos(_DegreeToRadien / 2)) + _ObjectXCenter),
        (int)(((_xOffset) * Math.sin(_DegreeToRadien / 2)) + _ObjectYCenter)
    );
```

It works with X offset but for some reason I can't figure out the Y offset without it going strange.

//------- The Answer ----------//
For all those who are wondering how I've done this here is the answer:

```
    //For left track

    //Decide how far away the track is from the tank
    _xOffset = _itemAnimation.getHeight() / 1.5;

    //Decide where the track is horizontally to the tank (Ie front, back)
    _DegreeToRadien = Math.toRadians(_degrees + 110);

    //Set the point of the track, takes the centre of the tank and adds the current position, cos and sin basically divide (though multiplication) the current position according to the direction the tank is facing.
    _trackLeftPosition.set
    (
        _ObjectXCenter + (int)(_xOffset * Math.cos(_DegreeToRadien))
        ,
        _ObjectYCenter + (int)(_xOffset * Math.sin(_DegreeToRadien))
    );
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to draw the tracks in the proper location with respect to the tank body?  What's it doing when it breaks?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to keep the tracks their constantly, atm they are only offsetting horizontally along the object.

Comment: Where's the code for the right track?

Comment: I fix the left one, the right one won't be so hard :P

Comment: post it when you're done, please, I'd like to see it.

Comment: No worries I will post it, I think I'm almost there.

Comment: I've posted the answer, I cannot answer my own question yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who are wondering how I've done this here is the answer:

```
    //For left track

    //Decide how far away the track is from the tank
    _xOffset = _itemAnimation.getHeight() / 1.5;

    //Decide where the track is horizontally to the tank (Ie front, back)
    _DegreeToRadien = Math.toRadians(_degrees + 110);

    //Set the point of the track, takes the centre of the tank and adds the current position, cos and sin basically divide (though multiplication) the current position according to the direction the tank is facing.
    _trackLeftPosition.set
    (
        _ObjectXCenter + (int)(_xOffset * Math.cos(_DegreeToRadien))
        ,
        _ObjectYCenter + (int)(_xOffset * Math.sin(_DegreeToRadien))
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

I need a little more information to help, but:

1. You can probably do what you want a little more systematically by
   using some matrix math.
2. Comment every variable in your code.  Sometimes this helps me find errors when things get abstract.

*Edit:*

This link shows how to rotate a point about the origin.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

If you represent your tank's components as a series of vertices with respect to the origin you can apply a rotation to every point systematically.  Then it's a small matter to draw lines between those points to make the rotated shape.  For example, if your tank is square, you could decide that its vertices are at (1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), and (1, -1).  Your tracks would be similar, but perhaps the left track would be (-1, 1.25), (-1.25, 1.25), (-1.25, -1.25), (-1, -1.25).  The same rotation matrix would rotate them all properly.  That would rotate them about the origin.  Not what you want but it's a start.

Then to get a translation in the x-y axis, you'd just add the X and Y coordinates the overall X-Y coordinate of the tank.

I don't have time to refresh my memory, but chances are a slightly larger matrix could also do the translation.  So the base coordinates, rotation, and desired (x,y) go in, and the final point coordinates come out.

This may seem more complex but your code would be smaller and less error-prone.

Comment: I'm matrices to rotate and scale my objects future down. Would they not impact each other?